# jQuery datatables dynamically changing is not removing correct rows in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using jQuery datables  with dynamically change columns using Colvis.
Everything is working fine (adding and removing columns).

But when the data is loaded and trying to remove a column, it is not correctly removing the corresponding rows. Instead just the column is being removed but the corresponding row data is being displayed in the next column. It should also be removed.

Pleas help to fix this issue.

CODE

partner.js

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "dom": 'C&gt;"clear"&lt;lfrtip',
      searching:false,
      paging:false,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": window.location.href,
      "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        console.log(sSource);
        console.log(aoData);
        console.log(fnCallback);
        alert('change in dataTable');
          $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
              // Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables 
              fnCallback(json)
          } );
      }
  } );
```

transaction.html.erb          # where the table is listed.

## this is where the data is being loaded in the each loop.

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Transactions</span>
    <%= render partial: 'date_filter', locals: {filter_name: 'load_more'}%>
  </div>
  <div id="merchant_list" class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-success">
      <table id ="example" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Merchant</th>
          <th>Bank Name</th>
          <th>Payment Gateway</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Discount</th>
          <th>Additional Charges</th>
          <th>Added On</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="details">
        <% @all_settlement_details.each do |sd| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= sd.merchantname %></td>
              <td><%= sd.bank_name  %></td>
              <td><%= sd.payment_gateway %></td>
              <td><%= get_status(sd.status) %></td>
              <td><%= sd.amount %></td>
              <td><%= sd.discount %></td>
              <td><%= sd.additional_charges%></td>
              <td><%= get_added_on_date sd.addedon %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="align">
      <% if @all_settlement_details.count < 1 %>
        <a href="" class="load-more" data-clicks="1">Nothing, more</a>
      <% else %>
         <a href="" class="load-more" data-clicks="1">Load more...</a>
      <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]      # BEFORE UNCHECKING STATUS COLUMN

[image]      # AFTER CLICK CHECK "Status"

See the two images. In the status column initially notice "**Status"**, **"Amount"**  columns. the  row data is "dropped" for "Status" column  but when I uncheck the status column, the  status column is removed but the row data which was **"dropped"** is now moved to next column Amount.

I could not understand why it is happening. How can I fix this behavior.

Comment: show us the get_status helper"?

Comment: @beck03076 The problem is not just with the status column(Assuming you're asking me for the get_status helper).
It is same problem with all the columns.